# How to use coroutines from Handle -implementation of IResult in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm loving the Coroutine/IResult implementation in Caliburn.Micro, allowing me to do have MVVM logic controlling several actions performed on the view.

However I'm facing the need to use the same approach when handling messages from the eventaggregator. My viewmodel implements IResult, which results in the following method:

```
public void Handle(T message) { ... }
```

I've tried changing the method to return an IResult or IEnumerable, but of course that does not compile, since I'm not following the interface then..

Right now I'm using an approach of creating a list of IResults I need and then call

> Caliburn.Micro.Coroutine.BeginExecute(routines.GetEnumerator())

But I'm not fond of that solution, and I'm not sure what threads the execution is running on. Also I don't have any context in my routines, but I understand context could be difficult since the message could have come from anywhere. However, if the viewmodel is ViewAware, one could get the context or?

What have others done in context of Handle -implementations? Any experience?

Hope for some cool solutions!

Comment: Can't help but I am interested to learn about what appears to be one more example of (ab)using C# iterator methods. Do you have a link to share?

Comment: From doc: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: It's not an abuse of interators. It's a well known technique for enabling co-routines, not only in C# but on other platforms as well. Async/Await in vNext is basically a customized version of the same strategy. When Javascript Harmony is released, you are going to see this same technique used with promises and generators there. It's already used in other .NET projects, Java and Ruby. I'm sure there are other places as well.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create your own EA based on Caliburn.Micro's that understands coroutines. We've thought about adding this out of the box, but I haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: This is a good idea; we've done something similar. This might also be a good opportunity to advocate for making EA a bit more extensible (expose some of the internals as `protected virtual`) since to get any different behavior, a copy-paste inheritance is needed otherwise. The way the out-of-the-box EA handles subscribers (with handlers) is a useful abstraction that is quite reusable.